# Parse Query ContainsString returns Invalid response

Tags: ios, parse-platform, contains, pfquery

I am using a `PFQuery` in my iOS app to search for group names that already exist in a class on Parse.com.  For my code, I have:

```
PFQuery *groupQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
    if ([groupQuery whereKey:@"GroupName" containsString:self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.text]) {
        NSLog(@"It Contains It %@", self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.text);
    }
```

The issue I am having is that it ALWAYS shows it contains it.  For example, the name of a group I tried adding was `Bazinga`  The current group names are `YWAM` `YWAM Kona` `CRICS Teachers`.  Yet, it always showed that the query already contained a GroupName of Bazinga.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the query

```
PFQuery *groupQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
[groupQuery whereKey:@"GroupName" containsString:self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.text]) 
[groupQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error == nil){
                // Great!  objects should only have the Group objects that contain thetext 
            }
            else{
                  // oops...check the error
            }
        }];
```